# How to get original image size in Dart Image.network?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

The following code gives `Division by null error`,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Image image = Image.network(data['image-url']);
    double widthToHeight = image.width / image.height;

    if(widthToHeight <= 0.2) {
      return NewsTileSmall(data: data);
    } else {
      return NewsTileLarge(data: data);
    }
  }
```

Best if, I could use a function to set the value of `double widthToHeight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build method you need to preload image.

```
Image image = new Image.network('image-url');
    Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();
    image.image
      .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
      .addListener(ImageStreamListener(ImageInfo info, bool _) { 
        completer.complete(info.image));
      })
```

Then you need to use `FutureBuilder`

```
FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
            future: completer.future,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData){
                return your image Widget}
              else{
                return placeholder widget
    }
```

completed build method

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

Image image = Image.network('image url');
        final completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
        image.image
          .resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).
          addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool syncCall) => completer.complete(info.image)));
        return Scaffold(
          appBar:  AppBar(
            title: const Text("Image Dimensions Example"),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
                future: completer.future,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.data.width}x${snapshot.data.height}',
                    );
                  } else {

                    return const Text('Loading...');
                  }
                },
              )
          );
      });
```

Comment: I can confirm this is the new way of adding a listener, but I get an error on ```completer.complete(info.image);``` : The argument of type Image can't be assigned to the type parameter FutureOr<Image>

Comment: @Nixel `build` method updated
Please recheck and reach me if any issues occurred

Answer (score 1):

To get the original size of a network image, you could use the [image_pixels](https://pub.dev/packages/image_pixels) library.

Here is how to use it:

```
Widget buildContent(BuildContext context, String url) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; // This is the screen size width
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; // This is the screen size height
    Image nimg = Image.network(url); // Preload the network image

    return Stack(children: [
      Center(
          child: Image(
            image: nimg.image,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            width: width,
            height: height,
          )
      ),
      // Wrap the widget that need to access the original image size in ImagePixels
      ImagePixels(
        imageProvider: nimg.image,
        builder: (context, img) {
          return Positioned(
              // Place a widget on top of the image, it's position related to the original image size
              top: 92.0 * (height/img.height), 
              left: 137.0 * (width/img.width),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print("On tap");
                },
                child:
                Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              )
          );
        },
      )
    ]);
  }
```